# What does vRS="\n20" mean on the gawk command line?

Tags: awk, gawk

Can any one please explain the below command:

```
gawk -vRS="\n20" '/Job-157625/' log.1
```

We are using this command to get the log for the job.

I know `gawk` is used to find/scan a pattern but I want to know why we have used -vRS and \n20 (why 20 has been used here after \n)

Answer (score 4):

man page for gawk reads

```
   RS          The input record separator, by default a newline.
```

So changes the record separator from being just a newline to being a newline immediately followed by "20".

Example below.

```
$ cat log.1
test
foo
Job-157625
20 Job-157625
$ gawk -vRS="\n20" '/Job-157625/' log.1
test
foo
Job-157625
 Job-157625

$ gawk '/Job-157625/' log.1
Job-157625
20 Job-157625
$
```